# What is the original 42 quote/joke?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

I tried to search the original 42 quote from google, but it would not give me much. I wonder, what is the original 42 quote or aka *the answer to life, the universe, and everything else*...

Comment: The original quote is.... pretty much what is says.  I'll pull that for you if you like, but your second question in the question is pretty much entirely opinion and isn't something we can answer.

Comment: @Edlothiad Linked question asks the background behind why 42 was chosen, whereas this is asking when/where it was first used.

Comment: @Mwr247 ah in universe not out of universe, my apologies. This should be left open (and made clearer)

Comment: Ya'll do know that 42 is eventually explained, right?  You just have read all of the books and connect all the little pieces.

Comment: All 42 books, yes. Unfortunately they haven't all been published yet.

Comment: @JRE: Indeed! It is the question that matters! And that question is....

"What do you get when you multiply 6 by 9?" Alternatively, it's something else completely different. :)

Comment: @Ernie Careful you fool! You must know that the answer and the question are mutually exclusive.  Knowing one means you can never know the other.  If both were known at the same time, the universe would be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.

Comment: Arthur and Agrajag are the only two characters in their universe who matter. The rest is only there to help those two interact.  Keep your eye on Agrajag, and you will find the final reference to 42.

Comment: @MrLister The final clue is in "Mostly Harmless," which was published long ago.

Comment: For the longest time I surmised the One True Question was not found because Arthur didn't have enough Scrabble tiles.  If he'd had more, the question would have gone on longer, "and subtract the number of roads a man must walk down" or the like.

Answer (score 40):

Keep in mind that the plot of Hitchhiker's Guide spends most of two chapters building up to this moment.  Descriptions of the majesty of the computer (which takes up a city), the initial disappointment as the computer states researching the answer will take several million years... and then we come to...

> "Good morning," said Deep Thought at last.
>
> "Er... Good morning, O Deep Thought," said Loonquawl nervously, "do you have... er, that is..."
>
> "An answer for you?" interrupted Deep Thought majestically. "Yes. I have."
>
> The two men shivered with expectancy. Their waiting had not been in vain.
>
> "There really is one?" breathed Phouchg.
>
> "There really is one," confirmed Deep Thought.
>
> "To Everything? To the great Question of Life, the Universe and Everything?"
>
> "Yes."
>
> Both of the men had been trained for this moment, their lives had been a preparation for it, they had been selected at birth as those who would witness the answer, but even so they found themselves gasping and squirming like excited children.
>
> "And you're ready to give it to us?" urged Loonquawl.
>
> "I am."
>
> "Now?"
>
> "Now," said Deep Thought.
>
> They both licked their dry lips.
>
> "Though I don't think," added Deep Thought, "that you're going to like it."
>
> "Doesn't matter!" said Phouchg. "We must know it! Now!"
>
> "Now?" inquired Deep Thought.
>
> "Yes! Now..."
>
> "Alright," said the computer and settled into silence again. The two men fidgeted. The tension was unbearable.
>
> "You're really not going to like it," observed Deep Thought.
>
> "Tell us!"
>
> "Alright," said Deep Thought. "The Answer to the Great Question..."
>
> "Yes...!"
>
> "Of Life, the Universe and Everything..." said Deep Thought.
>
> "Yes...!"
>
> "Is..." said Deep Thought, and paused.
>
> "Yes...!"
>
> "Is..."
>
> "Yes...!!!...?"
>
> "Forty-two," said Deep Thought, with infinite majesty and calm.
>
> *The Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy*, Chapter 27

... which is immediately followed in the next chapter by...

> Out of the corner of his eye Phouchg could see the sea of tense expectant faces down in the square outside.
>
> "We're going to get lynched aren't we?" he whispered.

Comment: I admit, I assumed and immediately went for the printed book, and forgot the radio play came first.  That's material I don't have access to though, so if it's played differently there, I won't know.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there was an experiment with some variables to feed to the Computer and the Computer spits out "42".  I didn't read the book, i can't be sure.

Comment: By the way, Is it the number "42" or the string "Fourty Two". :)

Comment: @Kaleab - probably doesn't matter what type the variable is (yes, I heh'd).  You ought to read the book.  Part of the way this is made relevant, and not just an extravagant punchline, is that seeking an Ultimate Answer to the Question of Life, the Universe and Everything is pretty pointless when you don't even know what the Question is supposed to be.

Comment: @Kaleab it is the number of pips in a pair of dice

Comment: I wish to state here for the record that it is not the string "Fourty Two".

Comment: Nor is it forty-two (correct spelling!), but the integer, 42. This is, in fact, quite important. :)

Comment: @Kaleab - the computer _speaks_ - it's not a printout on a screen or paper, it's spoken.  String or integer is not relevant.  Strongly suggest you read the book - this will help you understand.

Comment: How many roads must a man walk down? Now we know.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It's also six times nine, apparently.

Comment: @KSmarts IIRC, in base 13?

Comment: @KSmarts Sure. If you can read C, [here's a nice one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21835/most-creative-way-to-display-42/21887#21887).

Comment: This is a great answer, but the radio script answer is better.

Comment: @Jetpack - Um, OK?  You can say that with your votes honestly.  I gave the script answer an upvote as well.

Comment: @Radhil, I'm confused about the etiquette around here. My intuition was to express opinions with just my votes, but I've also seen people who feel an explanation is required, so I decided to try an explanation this time. Would it be better if I delete that comment?

Comment: @Jetpack Depends. If you want to go into a specific reason why you think one is better / more relevant / more complete than the other, then mention it as a comment. But if you don't go into any specifics, upvoting / downvoting is the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Misha R. My New Years Resolution is to be less quick to point out perceived errors. In this case, I was trying to say that the radio episode is the older version of the quote. Come to think of it I don't know what year this particular joke appeared in the books or radio show. I assume that this joke showed up in series 1 of the show in 1977 and the first book in 1979.

Answer (score 16):

The original radio script is pretty close to the novel, but here it is for the sake of completeness. Taken from a 1985 edition of *The Hitch-Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy: The Original Radio Scripts* [(photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8doCF.jpg):

> F/X:      DEEP THOUGHT CLEARS HIS THROAT
>
> TWO:      Deep Thought prepares to speak.
>
> DT:       Good Evening.
>
> ONE:      Good Evening... Oh Deep Thought... do you have...
>
> DT:       An answer for you? Yes, I have.
>
> THREE:    There really is one?
>
> DT:       There really is one.
>
> ONE:      To everything? To the great question of Life, the Universe and Everything?
>
> DT:       Yes.
>
> TWO:      And are you ready to give it to us?
>
> DT:       I am.
>
> ONE:      Now?
>
> DT:       Now.
>
> ONE:      Wow.
>
> (**Pause**)
>
> DT:       Though I don't think you're going to like it.
>
> TWO:      Doesn't matter! We must know it!
>
> DT:       Now?
>
> TWO:      Yes! Now!
>
> DT:       All right.
>
> (**Pause**)
>
> ONE:      Well?
>
> DT:       You're really not going to like it.
>
> TWO:      Tell us!!!!
>
> DT:       All right. The Answer to Everything...
>
> TWO:      Yes...!
>
> DT:       Life, The Universe and Everything...
>
> ONE:      Yes...!
>
> DT:       Is...
>
> THREE:    Yes...!
>
> DT:       IS...
>
> ONE/TWO:  Yes...!!!
>
> DT:       Forty two.
>
> (**Pause. Actually quite a long one**)
>
> TWO:      We're going to get lynched, you know that.

There are a few small differences to both the novel and what was eventually heard on the radio:

- It's apparently evening on the radio but morning in the book.
- There are three of the aliens talking to Deep Thought in the script but the episode reduces it to just two, a change the novel keeps.
- The two are credited as First Computer Programmer (Ray Hassett) and Second Computer Programmer (Jeremy Browne). They don't get names until the novel.
- In the episode, Second Computer Programmer adds a "Yes!" in the middle of one of Deep Thought's lines, right after "An answer for you?".
- Second Computer Programmer's a fair bit more confident about that impending lynching than Phouchg.

Comment: They are NOT Magratheans.  Magrathea is the world where they make planets.  Deep Thought was someplace else entirely.  After Deep Thought, the magratheans were hired to build the Earth as a computer to figure out the question to the answer.

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of the answer from a year ago

Comment: Except it quotes from the radio play rather than the book.

Comment: @JRE You're quite right. I've corrected it to "aliens" since "mice" isn't strictly accurate and doesn't make sense out of context anyway. As far as I can recall, they're never given an actual species name.

Comment: You say “what was eventually heard on the radio” but didn’t the radio episode come first?

Comment: @Edlothiad - well, unless the Improbability Drive got really silly and created a chicken/egg paradox (British, bendy space/time, why not), one assumes the script for the radio was written first, and then turned into the actual radio play.

Comment: Ah that’s what they meant, @Radhil, my bad

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember that the question was "What are six nines?", but I could not say if this came from the radio, the book or TV.  After a few minutes of "deep thought", I realised that 42 = 6 x 9 in base 13 [4 x 13 = 52, 52 + 2 = 54]. QED!  I have never met anyone else who noticed this.

P.S. I always wanted to ask Douglas Adams about this, but he tragically was taken from us too soon. In any case, would he have admitted (or claimed!) that this is what he meant?

Comment: The fact that 6x9=42 in base 13 is [*very* widely known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)), and even [acknowledged in the comments of the top-voted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173600/what-is-the-original-42-quote-joke/225707#comment466841_173601). Adams himself said that it was coincidence: "I may be a sorry case, but I don't write jokes in base 13."

Comment: F1Krazy: Thanks for that. I admit that I did not spot that when I skim-read the answers. (Also, I have only just discovered this site.) Please also note that although your circle of friends may be fluent in non-decimal bases, I doubt that this is generally true for the vast majority of the population!

Comment: Not a problem. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Why does base 13 important in the universe?